# gzip files as html source

Tags: asp.net, html, optimization

Instead of relying on the server to gizip compress css and js file, is it a good/bad idea to gzip the file, store these on the server and link to those files in the html.

Instead of

```
<script src="../Scripts/compiled.js"></script>
```

Have this:

```
<script src="../Scripts/compiled.js.gzip"></script>
```

And same with CSS?

I tried but it's not working; the files don't seem to decompress. I get `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/x-gzip:`  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Gzip file should have response header `Content-Encoding: gzip` while `Content-Type` should be `text/javascript` for JavaScript files or `text/css` for CSS files.

For me, following `.htaccess` rules does work:

```
AddEncoding x-gzip .gz

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.gz [QSA,L]

<FilesMatch  \.js\.gz$>
    ForceType "text/javascript; charset=utf-8"
    Header set Cache-control: private
</FilesMatch>
```

`Header set Vary: Accept-Encoding` can be used instead of `Header set Cache-control: private` to prevent returning Gzipped version to user-agents that do not support Gzip compression.

`.htaccess` file should be placed in directory that contains js.

Gzipped and nongzipped versions should be placed side by side (filename for gzipped version contains `.gz` postfix). Gzip-encoded version is returned transparently (if `.gz` version exists and browser supports Gzip which `Accept-encoding` request header is responsible for) when requesting usual file without Gzip mentioned explicitly in its URL.

P.S. Ah, you are using ASP.net, and therefore it's apparently running under IIS. Well, recent versions of IIS have `.htaccess`-like functionality, AFAIK.

Comment: Marat: Why have you got cache-control: private?

Comment: Fenchie: I don't think there's much to be gained by pre-compression on IIS, as IIS stores a compressed version of the files on disk

Comment: @Andy Davies: AFAIK, `cache-control: private` prevents proxies from chaching gzipped file that otherwise could be cached and then returned to all user-agents _regardless_ of whether specific user-agent supports Gzip compression.

Comment: That's what Vary: should be used for, proxy caching is a good thing!

Comment: You're right, each task has multiple solutions. In PHP, I use exactly `Vary: Accept-Encoding`. I'm not sure though, whether and how, via Apache's `.htaccess`, it's possible to append value for `Vary` header instead of replacing it (latter could not always be appropriate). I've updated my answer. Thanks for pointing this out.